Understanding the Purpose of a SubItem in ListView
I'm a newbie trying to make an Windows Form App via Visual Studio.
I am trying to read data from my SQL Server's database and display this on a table in the Forms App.
I'm using ListView for this.
To understand how to even use ListView, I've spent many days mainly using the Microsoft's Documentation. I have some questions to ask the expertise here.
Q1. What is the purpose of a SubItem and when do we need to use it ?
What I understand so far is that ListView is just a way to display items, where the items are stored under its Property 'Items'. Each Item is an instance of the class ListViewItem, where itself has a Property 'SubItems'. Each SubItem is an instance of the class ListViewItem.ListViewSubItems.
I've already read the documentation for ListViewItem.ListViewSubItems and they say that a SubItem is a way to put in additional details about the Item. Yet, when I see programmers add data in a row of their ListView (treating it like a table), they do so by
Step 1. Create a ListViewItem and insert their first data (in col0).
Step 2. Insert the other data (in col1, col2,...) by putting it in the ListViewItem's Subitems.
E.g.,
 row = new ListViewItem(reader[0].ToString()); // column 0
 row.SubItems.Add(reader[1].ToString()); // column 1
 row.SubItems.Add(reader[2].ToString()); // column 2
 row.SubItems.Add(reader[3].ToString()); // column 3
 
 listView.Items.Add(row);

I do not understand this system/approach of inserting data into ListView.
Why is the data being inserted into columns 1, 2 and 3, termed as SubItems of ListViewItem ? Why do we put it in the Subitems ? Yet data of column 0 is the "main" ListViewItem ??

Are you sure you really want to use a ListView. Have you considered using a DataGridView?  You'd set the DataGridView datasource to a BindingSource, then set the BindingSource's datasource to the datatable you get from the Database.

Hi @JonRoberts thanks for your comment. My professor had suggested the use of a listview and so was asking this question about it. I "know" how to use listview to create a table, which seemed almost like an ad hoc approach at the moment since I don't understand this class properly. But I couldn't find any detail/information which explains the reason why this approach is taken, with the term "SubItem".

The only guess that I can make is that the developer had intended to use ListView for a wide variety of things, maybe not initially for creating SQL/Excel type of "tables" with just text as entries.
That is, to them, the focus of their design of a listview was to simply be able to display items and to them, creating subitems maybe was needed for some cases.
Each item, along with subitems was then sufficient for one to make use of, to create tables, therefore they didn't bother creating a different property for creating tables.
